# Android add and remove fragments to FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have a tab layout and a view pager.  The tab layout always starts with a single tab, however, I want to be able to dynamically add and remove new tabs via buttons.

In onCreate:

```
mViewPager  = (ViewPager)   view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mToolbar    = (Toolbar)     view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mTabLayout  = (TabLayout)   view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

setupViewPager(mViewPager);
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

The setupViewPager method:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new CycleFragment(), "TEST TAB");
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

The viewPageAdapter class:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically add and remove fragments to/from the viewpager?  I understand via this method, adding new fragments is relatively simple.  However, how would I remove fragments?

Comment: In the addFragment() method you miss a notifyDataSetChanged(); otherwise it will crash

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.remove(title);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```